# Capturar centeúdo de uma página HTML com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estou fazendo um projeto a fim de curiosidade, e queria capturar o conteúdo dos links do meu HTML da página 1 e de acordo com qual link eu clicar, imprimir o conteúdo desse respectivo link na página dois

```js
var deb = document.getElementById('deb')
var cre = document.getElementById('cre')
deb.addEventListener('click', debi)
cre.addEventListener('click', cred)


function debi() {
  var valor1 = document.getElementById('deb').textContent
  document.getElementById('resposta').innerText = `O link em qual em cliquei foi o: ${valor1}`
}

function cred() {
  var valor2 = document.getElementById('cre').textContent
  document.getElementById('resposta').innerText = `O link em qual em cliquei foi o: ${valor2}`
}
```

```html
<h1>Escolha uma opção!</h1>
<p>Você prefere, pagar no crtão de crédito ou no debito?</p>
<a href="pág2.html" class="link" id="deb">Débito</a>
<a href="pág2.html" class="link" id="cre">Crédito</a>

<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<p id="resposta">O link em qual eu cliquei foi o: </p>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Esse é o resultado da segunda página:

```
O link em qual eu cliquei foi o:
```

Não imprime a variável!

Obs: Aparece o seguinte erro na ferrramenta de desenvolvedor do chrome.

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at script.js:3:5'
```

Comment: Se o compreendi você terá  *Página 1* e *Página 2* simultaneamente abertas e quer intercambiar informações entre as duas paginas?

Comment: @AugustoVasques isso mesmo, quero usar as informações da Página 1 na Página 2

Comment: Você se importaria se eu criasse uma nova pergunta baseada na sua pergunta?

Comment: Eu removi minha resposta dessa sua pergunta e passei para essa nova pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/557557/137387 veja se o ajuda.

Answer (score -2):

De acordo com este problema, é possível resolvê-lo a partir da seguinte análise.

> Você tem um arquivo JavaScript chamado em duas páginas, ao clicar no link para ir para alguma página, o script é carregado novamente com as informações da página atual onde ele está sendo referenciado.

**Mas qual é o problema a partir disso?**

*O JavaScript é uma linguagem client-side, ou seja é executada do lado do cliente e geralmente é utilizada para realizar interação entre dados e elementos contidos em uma página HTML. O arquivo JavaScript realiza o mecanismo de front-end de uma página HTML, definindo o que ela deverá fazer e como que os elementos (divs, botões, janelas) irão interagir entre si através de eventos e funções.*

Existem duas alternativas para resolver este problema, mas irei recomendar a última por ser mais fácil neste caso:

As páginas 1 e 2 precisam de comunicar para trocarem dados entre si e como o script direcionado para a página 2 não captura elementos da página 1, pela afirmação que havia dito anteriormente, podemos:

- Utilizar uma linguagem server-side (PHP) para passar dados da página 1 para a página 2, utilizando o exemplo abaixo trocando a extensão das páginas de `.html` para `.php` e passando dados para a página 2 a partir da url:

  `pag1.php`

  ```
  <h1>Escolha uma opção!</h1>

  <p>Você prefere, pagar no cartão de crédito ou no debito? </p>
  <a href="pag2.php?op=Débito" class="link" id="deb">Débito</a>
  <a href="pag2.php?op=Crédito" class="link" id="cre">Crédito</a>
  ```

  `pag2.php`

  aqui podemos ver em qual link foi clicado na página anterior acessando a variável `$_GET["op"]`

  ```php
  <p id="resposta">
      O link em qual eu cliquei foi o: <?php echo $_GET["op"] ?>
  </p>
  ```

  nesta solução não precisamos do JavaScript, pois passamos dados de uma página para outra por meio de uma requisição GET
- Utilizar o armazenamento local do JavaScript, que por padrão é o objeto `localStorage` que armazena dados na sessão atual do navegador, daí este erro `'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')` que aparece no Chrome foi por causa de que o DOM do JavaScript não encontrou nenhum elemento **#deb** ou **#cre** na página 2, dizendo que não foi possível adicionar o evento dentro do elemento porque ele está nulo, ou seja não foi localizado.
- Desta forma, podemos resolvê-lo removendo o atributo `href` dos links e considerando a tag `<a>` como um elemento qualquer e não como um link especificamente.

  `pag1.html`

  ```html
  <h1>Escolha uma opção!</h1>
  <p>Você prefere, pagar no cartão de crédito ou no debito?</p>
  <a class="link" id="deb">Débito</a>
  <a class="link" id="cre">Crédito</a>

  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  ```

  `script.js`

  ```js
  // declarando as funções

  function debi () {
      var valor1 = document.getElementById('deb').textContent;

      // colocando o valor no armazenamento local

      localStorage.setItem("op", valor1); 

      // indo para a página 2 sem o href após 1 segundo

      setTimeout(function() { 
          window.location.href = "pag2.html";
      }, 1000);
  }

  function cred () {
      var valor2 = document.getElementById('cre').textContent;

      // colocando o valor no armazenamento local

      localStorage.setItem("op", valor2);

      // indo para a página 2 sem o href após 1 segundo

      setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = "pag2.html";
      }, 1000);
  }

  // adicionando as funções dentro dos eventos na DOM

  var deb = document.getElementById('deb');
  var cre = document.getElementById('cre');

  deb.addEventListener('click', debi);
  cre.addEventListener('click', cred);

  /*
      capturando o valor da opção dentro do localStorage na página 2
      e jogando-o na resposta
  */

  var opcao = localStorage.getItem("op");

  if (typeof opcao !== "undefined") {
      document.getElementById('resposta').innerText = `O link em qual em cliquei foi o: ${opcao}`;
  }
  ```