# Como fazer a comunicação entre dois ou mais contextos de navegação com mesma origem?

Tags: javascript, html, front-end, cors, lado-do-cliente

Em um mesmo agente de navegação tenho duas páginas ou duas guias de navegação:

1. A página `index.html` que contém dois botões:

```html
<button id="btn1">Botão B1</button>
<button id="btn2">Botão B2</button>
```

2. A página `página2.html` que contém apenas um texto informativo:

```html
<p>Botões pressionados em index.html:</p>
```

Ambas as paginas interagirão em [mesma origem](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Origin).

Quero saber qual a tecnologia client side usar e como fazer com que ao pressionar um dos botões na página `index.html` seja adicionado um parágrafo na `página2.html` informando qual dos botões fora pressionado na página `index.html`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A resposta foi movida da [pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/557034/capturar-cente%c3%bado-de-uma-p%c3%a1gina-html-com-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em navegadores modernos a [API Broadcast Channel](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) permite a comunicação bidirecional entre contextos de navegação em uma mesma [origem](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Origin). Dois contextos de navegação são considerados tendo a mesma origem se e somente quando o esquema, host, e porta coincidirem.
A API pode ser usada para detectar ações do usuário em outras guias dentro de uma mesma origem.

O construtor [`BroadcastChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) cria um novo objeto `BroadcastChannel` e o conecta ao canal subjacente.
Como parâmetro do constructor é passado uma string representando o nome do canal onde existirá um único canal com este nome para todos os contextos de navegação com a mesma origem.

Ao criar um canal de comunicação, através objeto `BroadcastChannel`:

- Envie mensagens usando o método [`BroadcastChannel.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel/postMessage).
- Receba notificações de mensagens através do evento [`BroadcastChannel.onmessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel/message_event).
- Desconecte de um canal usando o método [`BroadcastChannel.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel/close)

> **Importante:**
> O exemplo abaixo não pode ser reproduzido usando Stack Snippets pois o
> site bloqueia terminantemente a abertura de janelas secundárias. Um
> exemplo funcional está disponível no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/broadcastchannel) onde será necessário
> para o teste do exemplo a permissão de abertura de popups pelo navegador.

O exemplo é simples, são duas páginas de *HTML* a `index.html` e `página2.html`.
É carregada a página principal `index.html` e essa inicia abrindo um canal de comunicação chamado `Canal1`.
Em uma nova guia á aberta a `página2.html`.
A página `index.html` registra dois eventos `click` cujo ao serem disparados enviam uma mensagem através do `Canal1` identificando qual o botão foi pressionado.
A página `página2.html` se inscreve no `Canal1` e regista um evento `BroadcastChannel.onmessage` que fica escutado `Canal1` e informa qual o botão de `index.html` foi pressionado.

*index.html*

```js
const bc = new BroadcastChannel('Canal1');          //Cria um canal de comunicação chamado 'Canal1'.
window.open("pagina2.html", '_blank').focus();      //Abre uma nova guia.
//Registra um evento click para o botão cujo o id é "btn1"...
document.getElementById("btn1")
.addEventListener("click", () => {
  bc.postMessage("Botão 1 clicado.");               //...Envia uma mensagem através do canal de comunicação.
});
//Registra um evento click para o botão cujo o id é "btn2"...
document.getElementById("btn2")
.addEventListener("click", () => {
  bc.postMessage("Botão 2 clicado.");              //...Envia uma mensagem através do canal de comunicação.
});
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Botão B1</button>
<button id="btn2">Botão B2</button>
```

*página2.html*

```js
const bc = new BroadcastChannel('Canal1');          //Se inscreve no canal de comunicação 'Canal1'.
//Registra uma escuta de evento...
bc.onmessage = (e) => {
  document.body.innerHTML += `<p>${e.data}</p>`;    //Atualiza o texto da página com a mensagem recebida.
}
```

```html
Botões pressionados:
```

- Veja a [lista de navegadores suportados](https://caniuse.com/broadcastchannel)

Comment: +1, foi bom ter separado a resposta da daquela pergunta, pois é um assunto que merecia ter uma pergunta com escopo mais claro e voltado só pra isso.

Comment: Como saber se está sendo criado ou se está se inscrevendo no canal de comunicação se as instruções são as mesmas?

Comment: @CypherPotato, é um canal de comunicação [full duplex](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex), ou seja os interlocutores se comunicam em ambas as direções. Então a mesma instrução(constructor) cria o canal de comunicação caso não exista um canal de comunicação com determinado nome, ou se conecta a ao canal cujo o nome já seja existente.